# Cohomology of BO(n) and BU(n) with coefficients in arbitrary ring

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

We know that $$H^*(BU(n);\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[c_1,c_2, \ldots,c_n]$$ where $c_i$ is the $i$th Chern class and $$H^*(BO(n);\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n]$$
where $w_i$ is the $i$th Stiefel-Whitney class.  My question is: what are $H^*(BU(n);R)$ and $H^*(BO(n);R)$ when $R$ is some commutative ring?  What can we say about the two?

Comment: For $BU$ it's just the same for the first with $\Bbb Z$ replaced with $R$. For $BO$ it's harder; there's a paper that calculates the cohomology ring over $\Bbb Z$. From there you work a bit to get it over $R$ via UCT.